# How do you assign the output of zenity -entry into a C language variable?

Tags: c, bash

I'm trying to get the output of zenity -entry into a C language variable. So far i can only think of using system and i still have no luck.

```
CVar=system("$(zenity --entry --title='TITLE' --text='TEXT')");
```

what i'm trying to do is get the value of user input from zenity entry and assign it to CVar. Any help ?

Comment: That is not how `system()` works so the very first advise is to read up on it.

Answer (score 1):

The `system()` function returns the status code of the command you executed, not its output. On POSIX-like operating systems, you can use the `popen()` function to execute an external command, receiving what it prints out.